# Sharing ASP.NET Session State With WCF Session

Tags: wcf

**How can I share my asp.net session with wcf session .**

Say I have a Session["UserId"] in my asp.net application . I want to access this inside the WCF Signature .
I enabled aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" in Webconfig & `[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]` in WCF.
I don't want to pass this session as an argument .
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't share an ASP.NET Session with WCF instance since they are in different Application Domains and could well be on different machines.

Here's a good article on [Instance Context Sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354514.aspx) which will get you some way with "persistence session" in WCF. Then it's a question of passing shared data over the wire (or by using a common resource/database etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you add this under `<serviceModel>` in your Web.config, it will work.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

It probably decreases performance a bit.